# How to handle/suppress Spring Boot DispatcherServlet exceptions related to URLDecoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, decoding, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a fairly simple Spring Boot 3.1 application (with Spring Security) that has needs to have a public endpoint exposed.

At times, I see errors like this one in the logs which are not caused by myself but an unknown third party:

```
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
    at java.base/java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:230)
```

I understand this error is caused by invalid `PUT`, `POST`, and `PATCH` requests to the application (see `curl` to reproduce below). My application does *not* expose endpoints allowing such methods.

**Question: How can/should I handle/surpress this and other `URLDecoder` related errors that don't apply to my application?**

Goal: I don't want these error logs and if there is a security vulnerability, I would like to close it.

I have tried:

*1 - Denying requests altogether*

As my application only handles `GET`/`POST` request, I thought I could simply add something along the lines of `auth.requestMatchers(PUT, "/**").denyAll();` to my `SecurityFilterChain`.

While valid requests are being denied as expected, it appears that the `URLDecoder` gets to work before the request even hits the `SecurityFilterChain`. This means that invalid requests such as the below still reach the `URLDecoder` and cause the above error:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 'http://localhost:8080/a-non-existing-endpoint' -d "%@"
```

I assume the reason for this is that "[AuthorizationFilter Is Last By Default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#_authorizationfilter_is_last_by_default)".

*2 - @ControllerAdvice*

While not very good for other areas of the application, I have even attempted another radical approach: using `@ControllerAdvice` for every `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor {

  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException e) throws IOException {
    log.warn("This is not being called");
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Some error"));
  }
}
```

However, this method is not executed when the request is invalid (see `curl` above).

I would appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (but not sure if this is a good way/best way of dealing with this) is to **create a custom filter** that takes precedence over the `FormContentFilter`.

**Why?** If the `Content-Type` of a request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the `FormContentFilter` will eventually cause the `URLDecoder` to be invoked in order to decode. Now, if the request is invalid (e.g. contains illegal hex characters in my example), an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

To be more precise, `FormContentFilter.parseIfNecessary(...)` may call `FormHttpMessageConverter.read(...)` which, in turn, calls `URLDecoder.decode(...)` where the exception is thrown.

**How?** Here's a radical example that simply blocks all `PATCH`/`PUT`/`DELETE`:

```
@Component
@Order(-10000)
public class HttpMethodFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final List<String> blockedMethods =
      Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.PUT.name(), HttpMethod.PATCH.name(), HttpMethod.DELETE.name());

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    var method = request.getMethod().toUpperCase();
    if (blockedMethods.contains(method)) {
      // Do whatever you need to do
      response.setStatus(400);
      return;
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

Note that `@Order(-10000)` is critical here. This is because the order value of the `FormContextFilter` appears to be `-9900`, so the value has to be lower than that in order to take precedence.

**Tip:** An easy way to see the existing filters/any order in your application is to set a breakpoint somewhere in `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain` to see the `ApplicationFilterConfig[] filters`. This way, you'll be able to see all of them, including their order which goes from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (highest precedence) to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (lowest precedence).